# getView() switch always going into default

Tags: android

```
 public class Inventory extends ListActivity  {

private ArrayList<Item> inv = new ArrayList<Item>();

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    this.requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.inventory);
    inv.add(new Item("Snake", 0, 50));
    inv.add(new Item("Snowball", 1, 200));
    inv.add(new Item("Stone", 4, 1000));

    setListAdapter(new ColorAdapter(this, R.layout.row, inv));
}


private class ColorAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<Item> {

    public ColorAdapter(Context context, int textViewResourceId, ArrayList<Item> inv) {
        super(context, textViewResourceId, inv);
    }

    @Override
    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        View view = super.getView(position, convertView, parent);

        Item item = inv.get(position);

        TextView label = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.invrow);

        switch(position){
        case 0:
            label.setTextColor(Color.GRAY);
        case 1:
            label.setTextColor(Color.BLACK);
        default:
            label.setTextColor(Color.BLUE);
        }

        return view;
    }
}
```

I am learning Android and I am trying to make a list with elements of different color. I already made this custom Adapter. To make sure it works I just wanted to make the first two items a different color, but the text is always set to blue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change your `switch` to:

```
switch(position) {
case 0:
    label.setTextColor(Color.GRAY);
    break;

case 1:
    label.setTextColor(Color.BLACK);
    break;

default:
    label.setTextColor(Color.BLUE);
}
```

Otherwise it will run through all of them and end on the last one. (http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/switch.html)

Comment: Yeah, I know, but I have to wait till I can accept your answer (15 mins after asking I think). :)

Comment: My bad! Thanks. I've been burned before :)